# Error calling templated pointer-to-member function with a return type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, pointer-to-member, template-argument-deduction

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename ...Args>
auto f(F h, Args&&... args) -> decltype(h(args...)) {
    T* t = new T(); // Don't worry, my actual code doesn't do this
    return (t->h)(args...);
}

struct G {
    int g() {
        return 5;
    }
};

int main() {
    int k = f<G>(&G::g);
}
```

Microsoft's compiler says `error C2672: 'f': no matching overloaded function found` and `error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type f(F,Args &&...)'`.

Clang's compiler says `note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with T = G, F = int (G::*)(), Args = <>]: called object type 'int (G::*)()' is not a function or function pointer` and `error: no matching function for call to 'f'`.

I'm pretty sure `int (G::*)()` is a function pointer ... ? What am I missing? (All of this worked fine before I added the return type.)

Comment: Compiler is telling you all. You can't call `h(...)`, because `h` is not callable on itself when `h` is a pointer-to-member. If you are using C++14, easiest would be to simply omit traliling return type.

Comment: I don't understand how that worked. What do you mean by h not being callable on itself?

Comment: Oh wait I get it, you can't call just h() you need t->h.

Comment: You can use something like `decltype((std::declval<T>().*h)(args...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm pretty sure `int (G::*)()` is a function pointer ... ? What am I missing?

Non exactly: `int (G::*)()` is a pointer to a non-static method. That isn't exactly the same things and require a little different syntax to call it.

So, instead of

```
return (t->h)(args...);
```

you should add a `*` and call `h()` as follows

```
return (t->*h)(args...);
// ........^  add this *
```

The `decltype()` is also wrong. If you can use at least C++14, you can avoid it and simply use `auto` as return type

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename ...Args>
auto f (F h, Args&&... args) {
    T* t = new T(); 
    return (t->*h)(args...);
}
```

otherwise, if you must use C++11, you can include `<utility>` and use `std::declval()` as follows

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename ...Args>
auto f(F h, Args&&... args) -> decltype((std::declval<T*>()->*h)(args...)) { 
    T* t = new T(); // .................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return (t->*h)(args...);
}
```

But there is another way to write your `f()` function: deducing the returned type (so avoiding the `auto`, the `decltype()` and the `std::declval()`) and  the arguments of `h()`

You can write `f()` as follows

```
template<typename R, typename T, typename ... As1, typename ... As2>
R f(R(T::*h)(As1...), As2 && ... args) {
    T* t = new T();
    return (t->*h)(args...);
}
```

and you avoid to explicit the `G` type calling it

```
int k = f(&G::g);
// .....^^^^^^^^   no more explicit <G> needed
```

because the `T` template type is deduced from the argument `&G::g`.